# Convergence in a finite metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's look at a metric space $(X,d)$
So we know that a set $A$ is closed iff for each convergent sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ from $A$,
we have $x\in A$

However, if $X$ is finite, how can we look at such defenition?

Comment: $(x_n)$ need not consist of distinct points. The same criterion applies to finite metric spaces also.

Comment: Well, it is the same. Just that your metric may have a definition with which you are less familiar with.

Comment: So lets say that $X=\left \{ 1,2 \right \}$
A convergent series would be $1,1,1,1,1,1...,1$, I see what you mean.

So which interesting or non-trivial things can happen in such finite metric space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite metric space is discrete (every set is open), so every set is closed.

This means the only convergent sequences are those that are eventually constant. Since all $x_n\in A$, then $x\in A$ because $x_n=x$ for all sufficiently large $n$.